# NgModel vs ngModel in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2 , While going through blogs  on Angular2 , I have come across `NgModel` and `ngModel`. 
I understand that `[(ngModel)]` is used for two way binding.
Can any one explain whats the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NgModel` is the class that implements the `ngModel` directive.
`ngModel` is the selector of that directive.
This means in HTML you use `ngModel` like

```
<input [(ngModel)]="someProp">
```

but if you need to inject it (for example for a `ControlValueAccessor`) you inject a class instance

```
constructor(private ngModel:NgModel) {}
```

where `ngModel` is just a variable name I choose and `NgModel` is the class where we want an instance get injected.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/26d1423ae93a743bd57a5fed9997c08c52f4bbfd/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L90

The source shows that because of `exportAs: 'ngModel'` it can be used like

```
<input [(ngModel)]="someProp" let-xxx="ngModel">
{{xxx.name}}
```

for example to output the `name` property (or any other property) of the `NgModel` instance that was applied to our `<input>`.